# What are the steps that one should follow if one loses their German residence permit (Aufenthaltstitel) while travelling outside of Europe?

Tags: germany, german-residents

Imagine the following scenario:

- A person is not an EU/EEA/CH citizen and is the holder of a passport that normally requires a visa to enter the Schengen area.
- That person's normal place of residence is within Germany and that person has been granted a residence permit (Aufenthaltstitel) by the German authorities
- That person travels to some location outside of the Schengen area.
- While outside the Schengen area, that person has their residence permit lost/stolen.

What are the steps that this person needs to take in order to be able to return to Germany?

Comment: Loss of Passport (§56(5) AufenthV) or Aufenthaltstitel [§57a Pflichten der Inhaber von Dokumenten mit elektronischem Speicher- und Verarbeitungsmedium nach § 78 des Aufenthaltsgesetzes - AufenthV](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__57a.html) must be reported to the local Immigration office. Outside of Germany you must report the loss to a German mission, who will inform the responsible local Immigration office. What happens then is not stated, but in the case of citizens of Türkiye it is known that the IO will authorise a visa to return to Germany. (this is an Expatriates question)

Answer (score 3):

Loss of Passport (§56(5) AufenthV) or Aufenthaltstitel [§57a Pflichten der Inhaber von Dokumenten mit elektronischem Speicher- und Verarbeitungsmedium nach § 78 des Aufenthaltsgesetzes - AufenthV](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__57a.html) must be reported to the local Immigration office. Outside of Germany you must report the loss to a German mission, who will inform the responsible local Immigration office.

What happens then is not stated, but in the case of citizens of Türkiye it is known that the IO will authorise a visa to return to Germany.